# How to get the text from a custom Listview?

Tags: android, onclick

I have a Custom Listview where each list item has three elements. how can i get the text of two  on click? I get the text of the first when i do what is shown below, but i need the first two.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, 
final int position, long id) {

                Log.e("item",list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()  );

     }
});
```

Comment: you have multiple lists to show data on a list view

Comment: If you want to get the text of item  then take onClickListener in your custom adapter.

Comment: You will be loading the list view with either an Array list or from DB. Use the position of the clicked item to get the values from the Array List or from DB.

Comment: @Leeds How did you pass the data to the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

As it is not clear from your question how data is passed to the adapter ,I'm assuming a ArrayList of objects.
In this case you can use

`list.getAdapter().getItemAtPosition(position).yourGetMethodForTheVariable()`

Or if you passed 3 ArrayLists you can

`SecondList.get(position)`

to get 2nd item.